# c# create Directoryentry with encrypted password

Tags: passwords, admin, directoryentry

We store Administrator user and password (encrypted) in database. And want to use encrypted administrator password when using `DirectoryEntry` C# like this.

```
DirectoryEntry loginDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("ldap_path", "administrator", "Password");
```

how can I do it, i don't want to write admin password in code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would do is use some form of two way encryption.  You can read more about that here: [Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string)

Then you would have the encrypted string in your database and then decrypt it when you're going to use it like this:

```
DirectoryEntry loginDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("ldap_path", "administrator", decrypt(database["Password"]));
```